# How can I output int type in web browser using mod_wsgi and Bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

**For string, it is output**

```
from bottle import route

@route('/')
def index():
    return '4'
```

---

**In case of int, it is not output**

・Why?

```
from bottle import route

@route('/')
def index():
    return 4
```

---

**environment**

・Python 3.6

・bottel 0.13

・Chrome

Comment: FWIW, an HTTP request cannot return an "int" anyway; HTTP responses are pure text. I don't know if bottle discards non-string return types though or if there's some other reason…

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with the code

```
from bottle import route

@route('/')
def index():
    return '4'

@route('/')
def index2():
    return 4

print("type of ", index()," is ", type(index()))
print("type of ", index2()," is ", type(index2()))
```

and I get that result:

```
type of  4  is  <class 'str'>
type of  4  is  <class 'int'>
```

Comment: @NeverTrouble.I changed the title. Will int displayed in web browser too?

Comment: I'm sorry, that might not work。Because that 'int' object is not iterable。[https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content)